# Question mark don't follow line breaks in Hebrew on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a Wordpress website that has just one page in Hebrew, which is a FAQ page. I am using Accordion to display the questions, the problem is that when the questions break into two or more lines the question mark insists on showing up in the first line.

I've created a testing page so you can see the problem: https://ethnicitydemo.com/ethnicity-3/testing-page/
Shrink the screen to see the questions when the break line happens.

I already turn the RTL option on. 
I tried to force a line break with  before the question mark without success. The question mark is always stuck at the end of the first line.

Does anyone have any idea of how to solve this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the expected behavior? Where you want question mark to be?

Comment: Hey Sam, I want it to be at the end of sentence, the very last character in the question.

Comment: add your code sample to your question, it's hard to tell where you have a mistake without seeing your code.